# syntax error for then and fi

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have written this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Greetings
#This program displays greetings according to the time of the day
#
echo
hour='date +%H'
if[ "$hour" -le 12 ]
then
    echo "GOOD MORNING"
elif[ "$hour" -le 18 ]
then
    echo "GOOD AFTERNOON"
else
    echo "GOOD EVENING"
fi
done 
echo
```

It keeps telling me, their is an error for the `then` and `fi` statement.

Comment: [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 2):

The `if`/`elif` keywords require some space following them (otherwise the shell won't be able to understand that they are separate from the following word):

```
if [ "$hour" -le 12 ]; then echo "hour is less than or equal to twelve"; fi
```